# Parallelize for loop inside a method

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing

I would like to parallelise the for loop in `fun2()` of the following code but I cannot figure out how. I would like to keep the function inside of `class2` and that seems to be why mapping to `multiprocessing.Pool` does not work. But I was also unable to make it work with `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`.

```py
class class1():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.var1 = x

    def fun1(self):
        self.result = self.var1**2

class class2():
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.var2 = y

    def fun2(self):
        for v in self.var2:
            obj = class1(v)
            obj.fun1()
            setattr(self, 'obj_{}'.format(v), obj)


obj2 = class2(range(5))
obj2.fun2()
```

This code works but is very slow in my case as `fun1` is very expensive in my real programm. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Multi-threading does not help with CPU-bound tasks. https://realpython.com/python-gil/#the-impact-on-multi-threaded-python-programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that. The change is in `class2`

```
class class1():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.var1 = x

    def fun1(self):
        time.sleep(1)              #simulate a long-running job
        self.result = self.var1**2
        print (self.result)

class class2():
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.var2 = y

    def _sub_process(self, v):
        obj = class1(v)
        obj.fun1()
        setattr(self, 'obj_{}'.format(v), obj) 
        print(f"in _subprocess, v is {v}")

    def fun2(self):
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
            print(p.map(self._sub_process, self.var2))        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj2 = class2(range(5))
    obj2.fun2()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code makes sense to me but does not terminate for me. It does not throw errors but won't finish. Do you have an idea?

Comment: This code doesn't finish? Exactly as is? Are you running it in debug mode or via an IDE, by any chance?

Comment: On another machine it works, I haven't figured out what is wrong there... But this code still won't write the five objects of `class1` into `obj2`. With a little modification I made it work though: I let `_sub_process` return `obj` and write them into `obj2` with `setattr` inside of `fun2`. This seems a bit more complicated than neccesarry to me but it still does the job.

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept my answer if you think it helps.